# WIX Bootstrapper Variables and Install Condition

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

Hey guys I'm back again for another wix question. I have been struggling with install conditions for packages. I am trying to provide user input reg what packages to install from check boxes in a custom ui.

I have 6 install packages and a variable for each one. When looking through the log I can see that "InstallSQL" is set to 0 but then later in the install process the log says Condition InstallSQL evaluates to true? Anyone know whats going on?

```
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:37]i001: Burn v3.9.10.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\Projects\CompanyName-ship\trunk\CompanyName.Ship\InstallerPackages\FullInstall.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{53BA8193-B632-410A-8DFD-BD8B3288A92D} {2CDCD7F1-DA19-44EE-B934-80E82B6D022A} 14292'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:37]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLSQL' to value '0'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:37]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallEpicor' to value '0'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:37]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallIntegration' to value '0'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:37]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallPrint' to value '0'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:37]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallWeb' to value '0'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:37]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\pwade\AppData\Local\Temp\CompanyName_Ship_Installer_FULL_20131226145937.log'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:37]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Projects\CompanyName-ship\trunk\CompanyName.Ship\InstallerPackages\FullInstall.exe'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:37]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'CompanyName Ship Installer FULL'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:37]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i100: Detect begin, 6 packages
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i000: Setting string variable 'Netfx4x64FullVersion' to value '4.5.50938'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i000: Setting string variable 'Netfx4FullVersion' to value '4.5.50938'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i102: Detected related bundle: {1d800337-d2b3-4e9c-843a-011118fff415}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i102: Detected related bundle: {3aed702c-5de7-4627-84ad-ccfe01665f5f}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i102: Detected related bundle: {c67d40e1-c5d0-40f2-9213-5da7f8d8c02a}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i102: Detected related bundle: {f8e8e3f1-ff22-4ce6-937f-e38b4c8493eb}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i052: Condition 'Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)' evaluates to true.
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i101: Detected package: Netfx4Full, state: Present, cached: None
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i101: Detected package: sql, state: Absent, cached: None
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i101: Detected package: epicor, state: Present, cached: Complete
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i101: Detected package: integration, state: Absent, cached: None
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i101: Detected package: Print, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i101: Detected package: Web, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T14:59:38]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[2B14:3544][2013-12-26T15:00:02]i000: Setting string variable 'INSTALLSQL' to value '0'
[2B14:3544][2013-12-26T15:00:02]i000: Setting string variable 'InstallEpicor' to value '1'
[2B14:3544][2013-12-26T15:00:02]i000: Setting string variable 'InstallWeb' to value '0'
[2B14:3544][2013-12-26T15:00:02]i000: Setting string variable 'InstallPrint' to value '1'
[2B14:3544][2013-12-26T15:00:02]i000: Setting string variable 'InstallIntegration' to value '0'
[2B14:3544][2013-12-26T15:00:02]i000: Setting string variable 'InstallUPSLine' to value '0'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i200: Plan begin, 6 packages, action: Install
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Netfx4Full
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i052: Condition 'INSTALLSQL' evaluates to true.
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: sql
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_sql' to value 'C:\Users\pwade\AppData\Local\Temp\CompanyName_Ship_Installer_FULL_20131226145937_0_sql.log'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i052: Condition 'InstallEpicor' evaluates to true.
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i052: Condition 'InstallIntegration' evaluates to true.
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_integration' to value 'C:\Users\pwade\AppData\Local\Temp\CompanyName_Ship_Installer_FULL_20131226145937_1_integration_rollback.log'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_integration' to value 'C:\Users\pwade\AppData\Local\Temp\CompanyName_Ship_Installer_FULL_20131226145937_1_integration.log'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i052: Condition 'InstallPrint' evaluates to true.
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_Print' to value 'C:\Users\pwade\AppData\Local\Temp\CompanyName_Ship_Installer_FULL_20131226145937_2_Print_rollback.log'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_Print' to value 'C:\Users\pwade\AppData\Local\Temp\CompanyName_Ship_Installer_FULL_20131226145937_2_Print.log'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i052: Condition 'InstallWeb' evaluates to true.
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_Web' to value 'C:\Users\pwade\AppData\Local\Temp\CompanyName_Ship_Installer_FULL_20131226145937_3_Web_rollback.log'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_Web' to value 'C:\Users\pwade\AppData\Local\Temp\CompanyName_Ship_Installer_FULL_20131226145937_3_Web.log'
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i201: Planned package: Netfx4Full, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i201: Planned package: sql, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i201: Planned package: epicor, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i201: Planned package: integration, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i201: Planned package: Print, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i201: Planned package: Web, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i207: Planned related bundle: {1d800337-d2b3-4e9c-843a-011118fff415}, type: Upgrade, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, dependency: None
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i207: Planned related bundle: {3aed702c-5de7-4627-84ad-ccfe01665f5f}, type: Upgrade, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, dependency: None
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i207: Planned related bundle: {c67d40e1-c5d0-40f2-9213-5da7f8d8c02a}, type: Upgrade, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, dependency: None
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i207: Planned related bundle: {f8e8e3f1-ff22-4ce6-937f-e38b4c8493eb}, type: Upgrade, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, dependency: None
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[2B14:30D0][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i300: Apply begin
[37D4:298C][2013-12-26T15:00:34]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[37D4:298C][2013-12-26T15:00:45]i361: Created a system restore point.
[37D4:298C][2013-12-26T15:00:46]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\pwade\AppData\Local\Temp\{bad38733-6dbe-4164-929c-436cd032182a}\.be\FullInstall.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{bad38733-6dbe-4164-929c-436cd032182a}\FullInstall.exe'
[37D4:298C][2013-12-26T15:00:46]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {bad38733-6dbe-4164-929c-436cd032182a}, version: 1.0.0.0
[37D4:1B3C][2013-12-26T15:00:47]i305: Verified acquired payload: sql at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\sql, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\4D9154DC35882713A8758870A321E8921694157E\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe.
[37D4:1B3C][2013-12-26T15:00:47]i305: Verified acquired payload: integration at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\integration, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{30F748FB-F604-4C0E-A55C-00A7277A7359}v3.0.0.0\ShipIntegrationServiceSetup.msi.
[37D4:1B3C][2013-12-26T15:00:47]i304: Verified existing payload: Print at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{6E19C8AA-976C-46ED-9D61-FC878D62541B}v1.1.0.5\ShipPrintMonitorServiceSetup.msi.
[37D4:1B3C][2013-12-26T15:00:50]i304: Verified existing payload: Web at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{9834D8A9-F7AA-471A-AB07-756D08A4C598}v1.0.0.1\ShipWebServerSetup.msi.
[37D4:298C][2013-12-26T15:00:50]i301: Applying execute package: sql, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\4D9154DC35882713A8758870A321E8921694157E\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\4D9154DC35882713A8758870A321E8921694157E\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe"'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like in Windows Installer, Burn interprets the existence of a string variable as boolean truth. If you want to use 0 and 1, switch to using a numeric variable. Otherwise, set a string variable to 1 to indicate truth and empty to indicate falsity.